# Step-by-step solution for a Limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is it possible in Mathematica to get a step-by-step evaluation of some functions? Such that Mathematica is outputting not only the result but all the stages that have led to it? If so, how does one do it?

I saw some ways to do so for computing derivatives, but i would like to know if it is possible for a limit.
For example (what I actually would need to know) the command

Limit[
$\frac{1}{L} \cdot \left( \left(\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+i\frac{\kappa}{L}}\frac{\left( 1-e^{i2\sqrt{k^2+i\frac{\kappa}{L}} L}\right) }{\left(1+e^{i2\sqrt{k^2+i\frac{\kappa}{L}} L} \right)}}{k+\sqrt{k^2+i\frac{\kappa}{L}}\frac{\left( 1-e^{i2\sqrt{k^2+i\frac{\kappa}{L}} L}\right) }{\left(1+e^{i2\sqrt{k^2+i\frac{\kappa}{L}} L} \right)}}\right)- \left( \frac{k-\kappa}{k+\kappa}\right)\right) $ , $L\to 0$]

does give me the solution
$$\frac{2ik(-3k^2+\kappa^2)}{3(k+\kappa)^2} $$

but i would be glad to know the calculation steps Mathematica did.

Mathematica code:

```
Limit[1/L*((((k-Sqrt[k^2 + I*(κ/L)]) + (k + Sqrt[k^2 + I* 
(κ/L)])*Exp[I*2*Sqrt[k^2 + I*(κ/L)]*L])/((k + Sqrt[k^2 + I*(κ/L)]) + (k 
- Sqrt[k^2 + I*(κ/L)])*Exp[I*2*Sqrt[k^2 + I*(κ/L)]*L])) - ((k - κ)/(k + 
κ))), L -> 0]
```

Comment: Your question appears from time to time.  In general, the answer is "No".

Comment: @Moo Sorry i am new here, can i just copy the Mathematica code in here, or do i need to know something else to do this?

Comment: @Moo okay, thank you!

Comment: In this case most likely `Limit` used `Series` to find a low order expansion at the origin, then returned the constant term after checking there are no negative powers in `L`.